# how to create an arc path from 3 points(x, y, z) in plane?

Tags: matlab, geometry, controls, tracking, robotics

I want to create an arc trajectory cross over n=3 points P(n)=(x, y, z), I decided to draw a circle over 3 points in plane. so I have center, radius, theta (angle in x, y plane) and phi(angle around z axis), and I know the position of 3 points (x, y, z), How can I extract an arc between p1 , p2 and p3 from this circle? I implemented this program in MATLAB..
Thanks a lot.

Comment: You have enough data to build an arc. Perhaps you need to define specific arc description for MATLAB?

Comment: Could you maybe show what you already tried in matlab? Or what you have so far? Also what kind of output are you looking for? A function? A custom class? A vector of points on your arc? A graph?

Comment: thanks for your answer. A vector of points on your arc!!in other hand my question is:  How can I calculate theta in parametric equation of the circle for each points? then extract an arc between p1 , p2 and p3 from this circle? I implemented this program in MATLAB..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer on math.stackexchange gives a nice simple formulation for finding the circle centre (and therefore the radius)

[3D coordinates of circle center given three point on the circle. (@Sergio G.)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2755842/283393)

From this other helpful math.stackexchange answer we can define any point on that circle in terms of the centre and two (non-colinear) points from the original 3.

[Parametric equation of a circle in 3D given center and two points on the circle? (@milbrandt)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2375120/283393)

Finally we need the 3 angles of your 3 points to define the arcs, which can be done with `atan2` and the component vectors created in the other steps.

The full commented code is below, which yields this plot, and functions to compute the circle angle for any 3D point, then the value on the circumference for any angle.

[image: circle plot 3D]

```
% Original points
p1 = [1;0;2];
p2 = [0;0;0];
p3 = [1;2;2];
P = [p1,p2,p3];

% Get circle definition and 3D planar normal to it
p0 = getCentre(p1,p2,p3);
r = norm( p0 - p1 );
[n0,idx] = getNormal(p0,p1,p2,p3);
% Vectors to describe the plane
q1 = P(:,idx(1));
q2 = p0 + cross(n0,(p1-p0).').';
% Function to compute circle point at given angle
fc = @(a) p0 + cos(a).*(q1-p0) + sin(a).*(q2-p0);
% Get angles of the original points for the circle formula
a1 = angleFromPoint(p0,p1,q1,q2);
a2 = angleFromPoint(p0,p2,q1,q2);
a3 = angleFromPoint(p0,p3,q1,q2);
% Plot
figure(1); clf; hold on;
args = {'markersize',20,'displayname'};
plot3( P(1,:), P(2,:), P(3,:), '.', args{:}, 'Original Points' ); 
plot3( p0(1), p0(2), p0(3), '.k', args{:}, 'Centre' );   
plotArc(fc,a1,a2); % plot arc from p1 to p2
plotArc(fc,a2,a3); % plot arc from p2 to p3
plotArc(fc,a3,a1); % plot arc from p3 to p1
grid on; legend show; view(-50,40);

function ang = angleFromPoint(p0,p,q1,q2)
    % Get the circle angle for point 'p'
    comp = @(a,b) dot(a,b)/norm(b);
    ang = atan2( comp(p-p0,q2-p0), comp(p-p0,q1-p0) );
end
function plotArc(fc,a,b)
    % Plot circle arc between angles 'a' and 'b' for circle function 'fc'
    while a > b
        a = a - 2*pi; % ensure we always go from a to b
    end
    aa = linspace( a, b, 100 );
    c = fc(aa);
    plot3( c(1,:), c(2,:), c(3,:), '.r', 'markersize', 5, 'handlevisibility', 'off' );
end
function p0 = getCentre(p1,p2,p3)
    % Get centre of circle defined by 3D points 'p1','p2','p3'
    v1 = p2 - p1;
    v2 = p3 - p1;

    v11 = dot( v1.', v1 );
    v22 = dot( v2.', v2 );
    v12 = dot( v1.', v2 );

    b = 1/(2*(v11*v22-v12^2));
    k1 = b * v22 * (v11-v12);
    k2 = b * v11 * (v22-v12);

    p0 = p1 + k1*v1 + k2*v2;
end
function [n0,idx] = getNormal(p0,p1,p2,p3)
    % compute all 3 normals in case two points are colinear with centre
    n12 = cross((p1 - p0),(p2 - p0));
    n23 = cross((p3 - p0),(p2 - p0));
    n13 = cross((p3 - p0),(p1 - p0));

    n = [n12,n23,n13];
    n = n./sign(n(1,:));
    idx = find(~all(isnan(n)),2);
    n = n(:,idx(1));
    n0 = n / norm(n);
end
```

Comment: If this answered your question, please mark it as "accepted". What do you mean the output "will be wrong"? That definition for `p1` will give the same data type (double) as what I've used in the example

Comment: can you explain more about your functions (angleFromPoint, getNormal, getCentre) in your code? please!

Comment: `angleFromPoint` works out the angle of the vector from some point `p` to the centre `p0`, relative to the two vectors `q1` and `q2` which were described in my 2nd link and are orthogonal vectors on the circle's plane. `getNormal` outputs the normal vector to that same plane; normally you only need 3 points for this, but I use all 4 in case two of the circle points are colinear with the centre (in which case the normal is not well defined) so it's more robust. `getCenter` directly (and blindly) implements the logic from my first link.